# Ionic 3 ion-checkbox checked attribute not queryable in Firebase subscribe function

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I've spent a while trying to track down a solution to this on Stack Overflow without any luck.

I'm using the Ionic 3 **checked** attribute in my html page as part of a list of contacts, as such..

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let friend of friends_profile_data | async ;">
    <ion-label>
      <h2>{{friend.name}}</h2>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [checked]="friend.checked" (click)="toggleItem(friend)" ></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

..and have the toggleItem function in the associated .ts file:

```
toggleItem(friend): void {
  friend.checked = !friend.checked;
}
```

In my test run with a dummy database I was able to successfully query this state of each 'friend' by using the following in the same .ts file (there was no  | async in the ion-content line for the local dummy DB)..

```
this.friends_profile_data.forEach((friend) => {
  var i =0;
  var total = friend.month.length;
  for(;i < total; i++ ) {
    if(friend.checked) {
      console.log(friend.name);
    }
  }                     
});
```

This runs through all the friends in my contact list, find the ones that I've selected, and gives me their names, not the ones that weren't selected. All good.

With that working fine, I've moved to hooking everything up to a Firebase database. Everything has been going well, except that when I tried to do a similar query as above within a Firebase subscribe function, it's not working. Here's what the code for that looks like..

```
this.friends_profile_data.subscribe(friends => {
  friends.forEach((friend) => {
    if (friend.checked) {
      console.log(friend.name);
    }   
  })                
});
```

Where friends_profile_data in this case is returning a similar set of data as found in the dummy local database, but from my Firebase DB.

Instead of only returning the friends that I've selected in the list, it's logging every friends name.. as though it's not registering the **friend.name** in the IF statement.

I've tried using alternatives, in case any of them worked, such as:

```
friend.checked = true
friend.checked == true
friend.checked === true
```

..but nothing works.

Should this be working? Is there some issue I'm not aware of that's introduced by doing the query on the **checked** attribute within a Firebase subscribe function?

Alternatively, have I just been lucky in it working with the local dummy DB, and there's actually a more robust way of approaching this within the Firebase subscribe function? The use of the **checked** attribute approach is from a tutorial I'd been through a while back in early Ionic 2 days.

Thanks for any insight anyone can offer. As this is my first post, I've tried to be as informative as possible, but please let me know if there's anything else I can add that would help in trouble shooting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling subscribe on the Observable, since this Observable contains an array of friends, you need to filter these friends using your rule first. You can use map function to transform the 'friends_profile_data'. It creates a new observable with the filtered content.

```
this.friends_profile_data
    .map(array0 => {
          return array0.filter(friend => friend.checked === true)
       })
    .subscribe(
       ...
    );
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, those functions are very useful. I have map and filter working for anything that is present in the Firebase DB, such as  (friend => friend.name === 'Some Name')  ..but seem to have the same issue where it doesn't recognise the ion-checkbox **checked** attribute **checked.friend**, which isn't present in the DB, but in the template.

Comment: The friends_profile_data variable is connected to the Firebase DB as follows in the constructor, if clarifying that helps in any way.. `this.friends_profile_data = this.dataProvider.angularfireDB.list(`/user_friends/${this.userCalendarProvider.user_id}/`);`

Edit for above, meant **friend.checked**

Comment: thanks sean. i am not familiar with ionic. i will do some reading.